# Press And Hold iPhone Screen

Tags: ios, screen, tap

So I am working on an app for an iPhone and I need to detect if the player is holding the screen and I need to get the location of where they are pressing.

Originally I was using the touchesBegin function but that is only called when the screen is touched a new time. Is there a way that I can modify this to be called more often, like every time the the update function is called?

Another thing I looked into was the UILongGesture stuff, but I couldn't get the location of where it was pressed.

Any help/advice to figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You tried the gesture recognizer's `locationInView:` method? Because that seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am being specific here on your question about how to get the location of where user tap,

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [tapRecognizer locationInView: _tileMap]   //locationInView is the method you need to try
}
```

Secondly, UIGestureRecognizer also gives you the state which may be useful in your case

> UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
>   UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded

and so on.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track - are you using multitouch?

If not, all you need to do is set a variable when the user touches the screen, then clear that variable on the touches ended function. Using the update function would work but is a super inefficient way of doing it

I'm assuming you want something to happen when they keep their finger on the screen. You could schedule an event in say 2 seconds when they touch the screen, and then if they release the screen before that you just cancel the event.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInView(yourScrollView)
    }
}


@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    var currentLocation : CGPoint = CGPointMake(location.x+translation.x, location.y+translation.y)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

This code finds the initial location of the touch, and then the new location whenever the touch is moved.  However, no code will be called without using the touchesEnded method.  I can't give you much more without knowing how you intend to use the touch.